# Отобразить содержимое метки яндекс карта (api2.1)

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Усть [яндекс карта](http://jsfiddle.net/AJIEKCEU/eLcnhw57/) как мне по нажатию удалить вывести в консоль содержимое маркера, тоесть мне надо знать каой маркер был удален(номер маркера). `placemark` как я понял, это балун, а вот маркер не пойму где.

Answer (score 1):

Placemark это как раз метка, а балун это один из её методов. Непонятно в чем проблема, запилить в   эвенте remove console.log?

Comment: как мне вывести текст который в метке, там стоит Метка 1, Метка 2, как вывести текст из болуна я знаю Placemark.properties.get('name'), а вот самой метки не нашол как